# Atom Jumpy enable on treeview

Tags: plugins, atom-editor, nerdtree

I'm using [atom](https://ide.atom.io/) with plugin [jumpy](https://atom.io/packages/jumpy) and [nerd-treeview](https://atom.io/packages/nerd-treeview) and 
 [atom-vim-mode-plus](https://github.com/t9md/atom-vim-mode-plus)
how can I enables the jumpy on the Nerdtree, so I can jump to specific files exactly like in Jumpy plugin

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of Jumpy.  This is now implemented in the newest Jumpy for the built in tree-view https://atom.io/packages/tree-view.

The nerd-treeview doesn't actually look supported anymore.  The default Tree-view does have a lot of hotkeys built in now though.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Vscode now, I got checked by how fast it is! it's really like a magical tool, but the Jumpy plugin doesn't work with vim plugin right there!

Comment: Ah, I'm looking to start development on jumpy for vs code shortly.  I didn't write the version on it currently.  It's a clone.

Comment: hey @challenger I finally released it! https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidLGoldberg.jumpy2  Let me know what you think and please rate it 5 stars ;)  It works with vim of course!